# Bent my iPhone 6 Plus, what can i do about this? It was purchased second hand

Tags: apple-store, applecare, iphone

What are some options if I bent my iPhone 6 Plus? I purchased my phone from craigslist so I don't have a receipt. Will Apple even take it back?

Comment: Can you post a photo to show how badly it's bent?

Comment: How comes you have Apple Care and not having the original receipt?

Comment: @duckx: how did you fare?

Answer (score 4):

Apple don't require proof of purchase for warranty service if the product went on sale less than one year ago.
Your best bet is to make an appointment at the Genius Bar and claim that the product is defective as it shouldn't bend.
The massive press attention on this issue is likely to make them more sympathetic.

(I used to work as a Genius in an Apple Store)

Comment: Claiming that it's defective seems a poor choice since it matters how it bent and how much bend is present. Most people are sympathetic to honest situations as opposed to what is clearly an oversimplification of "defective as it shouldn't bend".  I do agree that the best course of action is to contact AppleCare online or via the Genius Bar and get options on repair.